# C# Can I display images in a list box?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

C# In a nut shell can I display images in a list box? I have a list of users and I want to display a green tick next to some of the names, is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Winforms or WPF?

Comment: Steve, this article might point you in the right direction: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/glistbox.aspx

Comment: I would just like to say that I highly recommend not using that tutorial. It's very buggy, leaves the reader with too many questions and is poorly coded.

Answer (score 30):

The following code displays how to do custom drawing in a listbox.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Toolset.Controls
{
    public class CustomDrawListBox : ListBox
    {
        public CustomDrawListBox()
        {
            this.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable; // We're using custom drawing.
            this.ItemHeight = 40; // Set the item height to 40.
        }

        protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            // Make sure we're not trying to draw something that isn't there.
            if (e.Index >= this.Items.Count || e.Index <= -1)
                return;

            // Get the item object.
            object item = this.Items[e.Index];
            if (item == null)
                return;

            // Draw the background color depending on 
            // if the item is selected or not.
            if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
            {
                // The item is selected.
                // We want a blue background color.
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), e.Bounds);
            }
            else
            {
                // The item is NOT selected.
                // We want a white background color.
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), e.Bounds);
            }

            // Draw the item.
            string text = item.ToString();
            SizeF stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, this.Font);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(text, this.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.White),
                new PointF(5, e.Bounds.Y + (e.Bounds.Height - stringSize.Height) / 2));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

System.Windows.Forms.ListView will do the trick very easily. You might have to work a little harder than a ListBox if you want the list in 'details' view though.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF it's quite simple, but if you're using winforms, you can't do it with the System.Windows.Forms.ListBox control.  You *can* do it with the ListView control, or third party controls.