# How can I have an item like this inside of a Listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, items

Should I even be **using** a ListBox?

[image]

I'm talking about the Style control, and the Width control. How can I accomplish having these custom items?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to do custom drawing in a listbox. In which case the following SO question/ top-rated answer should help:

[C# Can I display images in a list box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472897/c-can-i-display-images-in-a-list-box)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, use the ListBox.DrawMode property.  Implement the DrawItem event to draw anything you like, it doesn't have to be just text.  The Pen.DashStyle is interesting here.