# How to use multiline textbox in order to use list item

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to use a textbox which has multiline `(TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine)` property.
But while writing any line in to textbox when I write like below (sample1), I want to show a list item icon like sample2.

```
(sample1)
Stack
Over
StackOver
StackOverflow


(sample2)
* Stack
* Over
* StackOver
* StackOverflow
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Use a `ListBox` instead. For example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2369/ImageListBox-exposing-localizable-custom-object-co or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472897/c-sharp-can-i-display-images-in-a-list-box or use a [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.listview.smallimagelist(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: textBox1.Multiline = true;

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most elegant way but it works for me. Use the `Key_Up` event and catch the `Return` key :

```
private void TextBox1_KeyUp(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)    {

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return) {

        string[] TextLines = TextBox1.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine);

        TextBox1.Text = "";    

        foreach ( txLine in TextLines) {

            if (!txLine.Contains("*") & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txLine.Trim)) {
                txLine = "* " + txLine;    
            }

            TextBox1.Text += (txLine + Environment.NewLine);    
        }

        TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.Text.Length;
        TextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
    }    
}
```

Note That you will get an empty line in between the lines, I'll let you fix it :-)