# C# image selection box

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make a application that works like a library of films. I want to put a list of images that show the film but I want them to be in a sort of scroll box so the form dose not have to be huge is there a way for me to do this I could not find a lot of help with this online.

So basically I want to make a scroll box that works with images instead of text, I want it to be like I.M.D.B (http://www.imdb.com) just a long list of films and a description next to them.

This is a for an application in Visual C# Express 2010

Comment: Winforms or Wpf or Asp.net ?

Comment: or WPF or SilverLight?

Comment: You are wanting an Image Carousel, that should let you know what to google for. http://www.bing.com/search?q=image+carousel+winforms&form=QBRE&pc=APPL&pq=image+carousel+winforms&sc=3-17&sp=-1&sk=

Answer (score 0):

I think a carousel or a div with scroll should work if web pages is your case.

For windows forms, this may be helpful.
[C# Can I display images in a list box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472897/c-sharp-can-i-display-images-in-a-list-box)