# Checking the index of a picturebox image

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I am creating a card game where images are loaded from a imagelist and displayed for a short amount of time, then "hidden" - the image in the card changes. I need help with when I click any one of these images so that it will tell me what index the card has so then I can change the image in that card. This will be used by the last Sub in the code posted below; "CARD THE USER CLICKED".

```
Public Class Form1
Private Cards As New List(Of PictureBox)
Private randomnumber As Integer
Private UserChoice As Integer
Private Timer As Integer

Private Sub SetupCards(numberofcards As Integer)
    ClearGame()
    For i As Integer = 0 To numberofcards
        Dim PicCard As PictureBox = New PictureBox()
        RandomCard()
        PicCard.Width = 100
        PicCard.Height = 200
        PicCard.Top = 50
        PicCard.Left = 50 + PicCard.Width * i
        Me.Controls.Add(PicCard)
        PicCard.Image = imglist1.Images(randomnumber)
        PicCard.Tag = randomnumber
        AddHandler PicCard.Click, AddressOf Me.cardflip_click
        Cards.Add(PicCard)
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub ClearGame()
    If Cards.Count > 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To Cards.Count - 1
            Me.Controls.Remove(Cards(i))
        Next
    End If
    ' Clear the cards if they were already setup from a previous game.
    Cards.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub EndRound()
    'set all the images to back of card
    If Cards.Count > 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To Cards.Count - 1
            Cards(i).Image = imglistBackOfCard.Images(2)
        Next
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub cardflip_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim picture As PictureBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)
    Dim idTag As Integer = CType(picture.Tag, Integer)
    'MsgBox(idTag)
    UserChoice = idTag
End Sub

Private Sub btnstartGame_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStartGame.Click
    Dim howmanycards As String
    howmanycards = InputBox("How Many Cards?", "Please Enter")
    SetupCards(Int(howmanycards - 1))
    ListBox1.Enabled = True
    ListBox1.Visible = True
    For Each imagesNames As String In imglist1.Images.Keys
        ListBox1.Items.Add(imagesNames)
    Next
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If UserChoice = ListBox1.SelectedIndex Then
        MsgBox("correct")
        Cards(CARDTHEUSERCLICKED).Image = imglist1.Images(UserChoice)
        ' Cards(idTag).Image = 
    Else
        MsgBox("WRONG :(")
        Cards(CARDTHEUSERCLICKED).Image = imglist1.Images(UserChoice)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Out of interest, why do you appear to have [two accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48681708)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to get the index of the clicked card, you ought to just store the reference to the picture box itself. Add another variable:

```
Private Cards As New List(Of PictureBox)
Private randomnumber As Integer
Private UserChoice As Integer
Private Timer As Integer
Private ClickedCard As PictureBox 'This is new.
```

Then in your `Click` event handler set the value of `ClickedCard` to the picture box that raised the event (aka the `sender` of the event).

```
Private Sub cardflip_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim picture As PictureBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)
    Dim idTag As Integer = CType(picture.Tag, Integer)

    UserChoice = idTag
    ClickedCard = picture
End Sub
```

Finally, just use that reference instead of trying to get it from your list:

```
If ClickedCard Is Nothing Then 'Make sure that a card has been clicked, otherwise the below code will fail.
    MsgBox("You must select a card.")
    Return 'Do not continue execution of this code.
End If

If UserChoice = ListBox1.SelectedIndex Then
    MsgBox("correct")
    ClickedCard.Image = imglist1.Images(UserChoice)
Else
    MsgBox("WRONG :(")
    ClickedCard.Image = imglist1.Images(UserChoice)
End If
```

You must also update your `ClearGame()` method so that it sets `ClickedCard` to null:

```
Private Sub ClearGame()
    ...the rest of your code...

    ClickedCard = Nothing
End Sub
```