# Create a custom list in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create an interface where rows in a table can be viewed in a manner similar to this (from Power Apps). Is anybody aware of a way this can be achieved in WinForms? Maybe there are some custom controls I can download and add to the project?

I could in theory instantiate controls one by one. But that would take a while/it would be difficult to make that scrollable (or at least I don't know how). Thank you for any ideas.

[image]

Comment: Easier in WPF.  Winforms?  You're looking at the DrawMode property and the DrawItem event.

Comment: Alternatively there are UserControls. A picturebox, label and maybe a button with some carefully selected properties exposed.

Comment: Or you could roll your own and override the default ListBox behaviour https://stackoverflow.com/a/473410/495455 with a full example here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2091/ListBox-with-Icons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something light-duty, it's pretty easy to use a flow layout panel to show a bound table in a scrollable list. A quick proof-of-concept is shown below [[clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/flowpanel-of-usercontrol.git)].

*For production use or with huge tables there are at least three major companies producing sophisticated custom WinForms components of this nature that have free trial licenses. IMO one "might" want to weight the benefits vs the cost.*

[image: screenshot]

```
class CustomFlowLayoutTable : FlowLayoutPanel
{
    public CustomFlowLayoutTable()
    {
        AutoScroll = true;
        Products.ListChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            switch (e.ListChangedType)
            {
                case ListChangedType.ItemAdded:
                    Controls.Add(Products[e.NewIndex]);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        };
    }
    public BindingList<ProductCard> Products = new BindingList<ProductCard>();
}
```

---

**ProductCard**

```
public partial class ProductCard : UserControl
{
    int _id = 0;
    public ProductCard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Name = $"userControl{_id++}";  // No space, start with lowercase
        Padding = new Padding(0);
        Margin = new Padding(2);
        pictureBox.Padding = new Padding(8);
        labelExp.Click += (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show($"{this}");
    }
    public string Description
    {
        get => labelDescription.Text;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(labelDescription.Text, value))
            {
                labelDescription.Text = value;
                var imagePath = Path.Combine(
                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                    "Images",
                    $"{Description}.png"
                );
                // Set the "Copy to Output Directory" property of all image files.
                if (File.Exists(imagePath))
                {
                    pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public string Category
    {
        get => labelCategory.Text;
        set => labelCategory.Text = value;
    }
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        Width = getWidth();
        // Respond to width changes of owner container.
        Parent.SizeChanged += (sender, e) => Width = getWidth();
    }
    int VSBW { get; } = SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;

    private int getWidth() =>
        Parent.Width -
            Parent.Padding.Left -
            Parent.Padding.Right -
            Margin.Left -
            Margin.Right -
            VSBW;
    public override string ToString() =>
        $"{Category}{Environment.NewLine}{Description}";
}
```

---

**Main Form**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        flowLayoutPanel.Products.Add(new ProductCard
        {
            Category = "Carpet",
            Description = "Caserta Stone Beige",
        });
        flowLayoutPanel.Products.Add(new ProductCard
        {
            Category = "Carpet",
            Description = "Caserta Sky Grey",
        });
        flowLayoutPanel.Products.Add(new ProductCard
        {
            Category = "Carpet",
            Description = "Ageless Beauty Clay",
        });
        flowLayoutPanel.Products.Add(new ProductCard
        {
            Category = "Carpet",
            Description = "Lush II Tundra",
        });
        flowLayoutPanel.Products.Add(new ProductCard
        {
            Category = "Carpet",
            Description = "Lush II Frosty Glade",
        });
        flowLayoutPanel.Products.Add(new ProductCard
        {
            Category = "Hardwood",
            Description = "Bolivian Rosewood",
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try it out tomorrow but it looks badass. I know peanuts about C# compared to you haha

Comment: Plz let me know if there's anything about the sample that needs clarification I'll be happy to break it  down.

Comment: Thank you I've learned a ton from this. I've never used a 'custom' control before haha.