# Form is not resizing correctly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Form where I display some data depending on some condtitions.
The Form is basically structured like this (each -> is a sublevel in the hierarchy):

Form -> TableLayoutPanel -> Panel | Panel | Panel | ...

I hide some of the subpanels depending on some conditions. That all works fine.
I use a scrollbar (`AutoScroll = true`) on the TableLayoutPanel. When resizing or closing the form I store the size in a database to retrieve the correct size when I reopen the form again. Now, when I open the form and hide some of those subpanels the scrollbar still appears although the panels are hidden (`Visible = false`).

The form gets opened like this:

```
Form f = new Form();
f.InitForm(); // get the Size from the database and hide the panels I dont need
f.Show();
```

[image]

The scrollbar is still there. Now I have to increase the size of the form to get the scrollbar hidden and then I can shrink the form again. When shrinking the size of the form with the mouse (after increasing the size to hide the scrollbar) the scrollbar appears only if the size of the panel is too less, which would be the correct behaviour. But I have to resize it manually.

I tried calling `PerformLayout()` in the `Load()` and `Shown()` event or at the end of my `InitForm()`-method but nothing changes. The scrollbar will disapear only if I increase the size of the form and then shrink it back to its content-boundaries.

One thing that worked is to say

```
void InitForm() {
...
subpanel1.Visible = false;
subpanel1.Size = new Size(0,0); // after setting the Size to (0,0) the scrollbar won't show up
}
```

So somehow the form or the TableLayoutPanel ignores the visibility and still uses the size of the hidden panels.

Does anyone has suggestions on handling the sizing problem? The only way is to set the size to (0,0) but there has to be a way around it.

Comment: Have you considered using a `FlowLayoutPanel` in place of a `TableLayoutPanel` for this? Just set the width of the `FlowLayoutPanel` to the width of your subpanel **plus** `SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75104373/5438626

Comment: I didn't try the `FlowLayoutPanel`, but the problem is more about the height as you can see in the screenshot where there is a scrollbar vertically but no content in this area. I want to stick with the `TableLayoutPanel` because I have some logic build in those and I generally use them in my application.

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar as far as multiple panels and only one displayed at a time.  What I did was to size all panels to the same size and then in my code, I stack them like a deck of cards.  Whichever panel needs to be shown, I use the panel command of .BringtoFront.

Another option would be to create each panel as a user control and then load it into a flowpanel as needed.  That might save you a lot of hassle with storing form sizes.

Comment: The subpanels need to be positioned below each other. And I try to avoid using the `FlowLayoutPanel`

Comment: Flowlayoutpanel is the way to go.  I use it to do what you're talking about in another appliction, now that I think about it.  Why avoid it if works?  Is there any reason to avoid flowpanel?

Comment: I need the `TableLayoutPanel` because I use the Columns and Row functionality of it. We use big Panels with lot of controls in it, I cannot simply change it to use the Flow-functionality and creating userclasses for each entity. Believe me, using the `FlowLayoutPanel` is not a valid option. I would rather use the workaround setting the `Size` of the hidden subpanels to (0,0).